# checkbox in google visualization table

Tags: javascript, checkbox, google-visualization

Please refer to the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/46/

I am using `google visualization table`, and making a `tree table` like above. Some column in `child row`, I attached `html` checkbox.

I question I am facing is that, if I click the `checkbox`, it is never checked. This is because in the `table listener`, every time a `select` event is triggered, it will redraw the table.

I look at the `google visualization table` [API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events), and find this:

> Note that the table chart only fires row selection events; however,
>   the code is generic, and can be used for row, column, and cell
>   selection events.

This means that if I click a column in row, I can never know which column I actually clicked? So I can not get the `checkbox` by `id`, and using javascript to make it `checked`? That sucks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `getSelection()` function does not preserve `column` once select event is triggered. But you could consider the following approach to preserve checkboxes states once the chart is redrawn.

First, we need to introduce object for storing checkboxes states:

```
var checkboxStates = {'cbox1' : false, 'cbox2': false};
```

Then we register `ready` event for saving/loading state once Google Chart is redrawn:

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', function(){
    //...
 });
```

And finally the following example demonstrates how to save/load state:

```
//load checkboxes state
for(var id in checkboxStates){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
    if(checkbox !== null) {
        checkbox.checked = checkboxStates[id];
    }    
}
//save state
if(event.target.type == "checkbox"){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(event.target.id);  
    checkbox.checked = !event.target.checked;
    checkboxStates[event.target.id] = checkbox.checked;
}
```

> Note: [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is utilized to track checkboxes click events

**Final example**

Below is provided the modified example of yours with ability to preserve checkboxes state

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['table']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'id');
    data.addColumn('string', 'parentId');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'visible');
    data.addColumn('number', 'level');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows([
        ['1', null, true, 1, 'Foo', 10],
        ['1.1', '1', false, 2, 'Foo 1', 2],
        ['1.1.1', '1.1', false, 3, 'Foo 1a', 2],
        ['1.1.2', '1.1', false, 3, 'Foo 1b', 2],
        ['1.2', '1', false, 2, 'Foo 2', 3],
        ['1.3', '1', false, 2, 'Foo 3', 5],
        ['1.3.1', '1.3', false, 3, '<input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="second_checkbox">', 1],
        ['1.3.2', '1.3', false, 3, '<input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="second_checkbox">', 4],
        ['2', null, true, 1, 'Bar', 14],
        ['2.1', '2', false, 2, 'Bar 1', 6],
        ['2.2', '2', false, 2, 'Bar 2', 7],
        ['2.2.1', '2.2', false, 3, 'Bar 2a', 3],
        ['2.2.2', '2.2', false, 3, 'Bar 2b', 2],
        ['2.2.3', '2.2', false, 3, 'Bar 2c', 2]
    ]);

    // get all rows with children
    // start by finding all child rows (ie, rows with parents)
    var children = data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 1,
        minValue: '1'
    }]);
    var parentsArray = [];
    var parentId;
    // identify the parents of all children
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        parentId = data.getValue(children[i], 1);
        if (parentsArray.indexOf(parentId) === -1) {
            parentsArray.push(parentId);
        }
    }

    //format the parent rows
    var parent = data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 3,
        value: 1
    }]);
    for (var j = 0; j < parent.length; j++) {
        parentId = data.getValue(parent[j], 0);
        if (parentsArray.indexOf(parentId) !== -1) {
            data.setProperty(parent[j], 4, 'className', 'parentcl close');
        }
        else {
            data.setProperty(parent[j], 4, 'className', 'parentcl');
        }
    };
    //format the 2level rows
    var leveltwo = data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 3,
        value: 2
    }]);
    for (var j = 0; j < leveltwo.length; j++) {
        parentId = data.getValue(leveltwo[j], 0);
        if (parentsArray.indexOf(parentId) !== -1) {
            data.setProperty(leveltwo[j], 4, 'className', 'leveltwo close');
        }
        else {
            data.setProperty(leveltwo[j], 4, 'className', 'leveltwo');
        }
    };
    //format the 3level rows
    var levelthree = data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 3,
        value: 3
    }]);
    for (var j = 0; j < levelthree.length; j++) {
        data.setProperty(levelthree[j], 4, 'className', 'levelthree');
    };

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    // hide the first four columns
    view.setColumns([4, 5]);
    view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 2,
        value: true
    }]));

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    var cssClassNames = {
        headerRow: 'gtableheader',
        oddTableRow: 'rowodd',
        headerCell: 'gtableheader'
    };
    var options = {
        showRowNumber: false,
        allowHtml: true,
        cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
        sort: 'disable'
    };


    var checkboxStates = {'cbox1' : false, 'cbox2': false};


    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function () {


        var sel = table.getSelection();
        recurseTree(view.getTableRowIndex(sel[0].row), false);
        view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
            column: 2,
            value: true
        }]));
        table.setSelection(null);
        google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', function(){
            //load checkboxes state
            for(var id in checkboxStates){
                var checkbox = document.getElementById(id);
                if(checkbox !== null) {
                     checkbox.checked = checkboxStates[id];
                }    
            }
            //update state
            if(event.target.type == "checkbox"){
                var checkbox = document.getElementById(event.target.id);  
                checkbox.checked = !event.target.checked;
                checkboxStates[event.target.id] = checkbox.checked;
            }
        });
        table.draw(view, options);

        function recurseTree(row, hideOnly) {
            // get the id of the row
            var id = data.getValue(row, 0);
            // get the parent row
            var parentrow = data.getFilteredRows([{
                column: 0,
                value: id
            }]);
            var parentlevel = data.getValue(parentrow[0], 3);
            // find all child rows
            var rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
                column: 1,
                value: id
            }]);

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if (data.getValue(rows[i], 2)) {
                    // hide the row and recurse down the tree
                    data.setValue(rows[i], 2, false);
                    switch (parentlevel) {
                        case 1:
                            data.setProperty(parentrow[0], 4, 'className', 'parentcl close');
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            data.setProperty(parentrow[0], 4, 'className', 'leveltwo close');
                            break;
                        default:
                            data.setProperty(parentrow[0], 4, 'className', 'levelthree close');
                    }
                    recurseTree(rows[i], true);
                }
                else if (!hideOnly) {
                    // if the row is hidden, show it
                    data.setValue(rows[i], 2, true);
                    switch (parentlevel) {
                        case 1:
                            data.setProperty(parentrow[0], 4, 'className', 'parentcl open');
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            data.setProperty(parentrow[0], 4, 'className', 'leveltwo open');
                            break;
                        default:
                            data.setProperty(parentrow[0], 4, 'className', 'levelthree open');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


    table.draw(view, options);
}
```

```css
.parentcl{
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
.close:before{
content:"→ "
}
.open:before{
content:"↘ "
}
.leveltwo{
    padding-left: 20px !important;
}
.levelthree{
    padding-left: 45px !important;
    font-style:italic;
}
.gtableheader {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: grey;
}
.rowodd {
    background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```